# adding custom variables to Twilio action urls / $_REQUEST variables using PHP

Tags: php, twilio

I did see this thread:  [Is it possible to add additional variables to the action attribute in the gather tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121392/is-it-possible-to-add-additional-variables-to-the-action-attribute-in-the-gather)

and that would work, but that would mean I have to set up my directory for mod-rewrite, and I was hoping for something a little more direct and simple.

Is there a way to append custom variables to Twilio PHP action urls ($_REQUEST variable) without literally writing them out?  When I add them manually it creates parse errors.

I've tried $_REQUEST['my_var'] = $value but it isn't working.

Comment: First of all, why would you do that? $_REQUEST is used to grab the request data, not to set.

Answer (score 1):

Insert into `$_POST` or `$_GET`. Not `$_REQUEST`.